# Animation in android pause the image after animation is done?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am creating an animation in android for two buttons.Button1 moves from bottom center to center of the screen vertically upwards direction(say in 2 seconds).Once it reaches there,the image should be there for say 2 seconds.Then the second image moves from center_right side of the screen to the center_left side of the screen while the first button is still present.Can some body please tell me how to make the first image be there for some time on the screen.Following is my code :

R.anim.alpha

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <translate 
            android:fromYDelta="200%p" 
            android:toYDelta="-11%p" 
            android:duration="3000"
            android:repeatCount="infinite"
            />
    </set>
```

R.anim.anim_card

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
      android:fromXDelta="600%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    />
</set>
```

And in Java code:

```
 Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    a.reset();
    _image.clearAnimation();
    _image.startAnimation(a);

    Animation b =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_card);
            b.reset();
            btn_card.clearAnimation();
            btn_card.startAnimation(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use AnimationListener for that:

```
 Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
 a.reset();
 _image.clearAnimation();
 _image.startAnimation(a);

 Animation b =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_card);
 b.reset();

 a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            btn_card.clearAnimation();
            btn_card.startAnimation(b);
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not Work @ TheReader.The first button continues the animation however the second button does not do any animation now.I have mentioned android:repeatCount="infinite".Once the first button reaches the center it should wait there for some time(it should remain on screen).At this time second animation should start while button1 is on the screen(at center).I am Sorry if i was unable to explain the scenario :(

Comment: @Joyson Ok.. And what should happen after second animation ends?

Comment: Again the first animation continues.Followed by the second.